# Can methods (not the constructor) in classes take parameters?

Tags: php, oop

Sorry this is going to sound like a ridiculous question but can methods (not the constructor) in classes take parameters in the function declaration?

All the examples I've seen of methods (not constructor) pass no variables but call variables already declared in the class with $this->someVariable inside the function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can:

```
class Foo {
    public function sum($a, $b, $c) {
        $sum = $a + $b + $c;

        return $sum;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->sum(1,2,3); //Displays 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, like any other function.

```
<?php

     class Foo {

        public function displayParameter($param) {
            return $param;
        }

     }

     $foo = new Foo();
     echo $foo->displayParameter("Hello World"); //Displays Hello World

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If a class represents some object, then you will have properties that can be accessed by the functions (methods). Static methods often accept parameters. So the answer is, yes, methods can accept parameters, but it also depends on how you use the class.

Answer (score 0):

> can methods (not the constructor) in classes take parameters in the function declaration?

Yes.

Answer (score -3):

Yes.  You can pass parameters directly or by reference if you want to change their value within the called method.  Let me recommend a bit of reading: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: Doing that is generally bad practice, doing that inside of classes is even more bad practice.